# OpenCL copy character from global to local memory

Tags: c++, c, opencl, opencl-c

I'm implementing sha512 in OpenCL technology. I have simple definition of kernel function

```
__kernel void _sha512(__global char *message, const uint length, __global char *hash);
```

On host I have implemented and successfully tested implementation of sha512 algorithm.

I have a problem with copy data from `message` array to temporary variable called `character`.

```
char character = message[i];
```

Where `i` is a loop variable - in range from 0 to message's size.

When I tried to run my program there I got this errors

```
0x00007FFD9FA03D54 (0x0000000010CD0F88 0x0000000010CD0F88 0x0000000010BAEE88 0x000000001A2942A0), nvvmCompilerProperty() + 0x26174 bytes(s)
...
0x00007FFDDFA70D51 (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x21 bytes(s)
0x00007FFDDFA70D51 (0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000), RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x21 bytes(s)
```

I readed about [async_work_group_copy()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html) but I can't understand how to use it - in docs I can't found any example code.

I have tried with `char character = (__private char) message[i];` but it's not working too.

I don't understand how to pass last parameter into `async_work_group_copy()` and how to use it to copy data from `__global` memory into `__private` memory.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL by default does not allow single-byte access in kernels: memory access needs to be in multiples of 4 bytes, aligned to 4-byte boundaries. If your implementation supports it, you can enable byte-wise memory accesses. This involves the [cl_khr_byte_addressable_store extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html), which you need to check for and explicitly enable in your kernel source. Give that a try and see if it solves your problem.

To use `async_work_group_copy`, try something like this:

```
#define LOCAL_MESSAGE_SIZE 64 // or some other suitable size for your workgroup
__local char local_message[LOCAL_MESSAGE_SIZE];
event_t local_message_ready = async_work_group_copy(local_message, message, LOCAL_MESSAGE_SIZE, 0);
// ...

// Just before you need to use local_message's content:
wait_group_events(1, &local_message_ready);
// Use local_message from here onwards
```

Note that `async_work_group_copy` is not required; you can access global memory directly. Which will be faster depends on your kernel, OpenCL implementation, and hardware.

Another option (the only option if your implementation/hardware do not support cl_khr_byte_addressable_store) is to fetch your data in chunks of at least 4 bytes. Declare your `message` as a `__global uint*` and unpack the bytes by shifting and masking:

```
uint word = message[i];
char byte0 = (word & 0xff);
char byte1 = ((word >> 8) & 0xff);
char byte2 = ((word >> 16) & 0xff);
char byte3 = ((word >> 24) & 0xff);
// use byte0..byte3 in your algorithm
```

Depending on implementation, hardware, etc. you may find this to be faster than bytewise access. (You may want to [check if you need to reverse the unpacking by reading the `CL_DEVICE_ENDIAN_LITTLE` property using `clGetDeviceInfo`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) if you're not sure if all your deployment platforms will be little-endian.)